# How can I rotate a pie chart in charts.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, chart.js

It looks like a pie in `charts.js` is drawn by taking a vertical radius on the top half of the circle, and then moving clockwise from there. This works great most of the time, but for a pie with only 2 categories, it would be nice if it could be rotated so that the slice is centered, like this:

[image]

The rotation is calculated by taking the percentage of 360 and dividing by 2. `(.14*360)/2 = 25.2` degrees left, so if I could just apply

```
transform: rotate(-25.2deg);
```

to the circle I would be good.

Since `charts.js` puts this on a canvas (as opposed to `<svg>`) I don't know how to apply any transformations to this. Not sure if relevant, but here is my code for the chart:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id=canvas style='width:300px;height:300px;'></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
openRate = [
            {
                value: 488,
                color: "#FF9030",
                highlight: "rgba(255, 144, 48, 0.44)",
            },
            {
                value: 3475,
                color: "#008DB7",
                highlight: "rgba(0, 141, 183, 0.82)"
            }
        ];

var ctx=document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
var chart=new Chart(ctx).Pie(openRate);
```

And a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/msy6kf3a/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You Can use the

> Rotation Options in [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options)

I'm using "Version: 2.1.6"

```
var options = {
   rotation: (-0.5 * Math.PI) - (25/180 * Math.PI)
}

var Chart = new Chart(ctx,{
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msy6kf3a/27/)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it's simply not a work-around

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate using CSS3:    **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/msy6kf3a/1/)**

```
#canvas{
   width:300px;
   height:300px; 
   -ms-transform: rotate(-25.2deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-25.2deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: rotate(-25.2deg);
}
```

Comment: zomg I just apply the rotation to the canvas itself, since I can't manipulate its content. (facepalm!) thank you

Comment: @JRulle the issue with this is, all labels will now be offset. Hover over your pie chart to see what I mean. Is there no way to rotate the chart itself?