# How to Reverse Chart.js Label Order?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using  a lot of pie  and doughnut charts  with two data values  in a
project. It really annoys me that since the chart slices starts from the
top going clockwise, the labels end up looking reversed: on the opposite
side of the data it represents.

[image: Chart.js Doughtnut Chart]

Is there an easy way to reverse the label order, or reverse the chart to
run counter-clockwise?

```
new Chart(context, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [ 'Blue', 'Red' ],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [7, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)',
          'rgba(208, 54, 100, 0.7)',
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992044/how-can-i-rotate-a-pie-chart-in-charts-js

Comment: Thanks @mkaatman it does help. But apparently the exact option I was looking for exists, check the answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `reverse` option under legend which will show datasets in reverse order

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html?h=reverse

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it `rotation` via `options` in the Chart object.

```
new Chart(context, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
labels: [ 'Blue', 'Red' ],
datasets: [{
          data: [7, 3],
          backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)',
          'rgba(208, 54, 100, 0.7)',
          ],
      }]
     },
  options: {rotation: (0.5 * Math.PI)}
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zdh7591r/

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, but it is not exactly what I asked.